# https for eks loadbalancer

Tags: yaml, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I want to secure my web application running on Kubernetes (EKS).
I have one front-end service .Front end service is running on port 80 .I want to run this on port 443 .When I kubectl get all .I see that my load balancer is running on port 443 , but I am not able to open it in the browser.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:1234567890:certificate/12345c409-ec32-41a8-8542-712345678
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hello-kubernetes
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-kubernetes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-kubernetes
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-kubernetes
        image: 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/demoui:demo123
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: MESSAGE
          value: Hello Kubernetes!
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: "/"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: "200,404"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: "internet-facing"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80} , {"HTTPS": 443}]'
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 2):

[AWS ALB Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/) is designed to create application Load Balancer and relevant resources on AWS level within Ingress YAML configuration file. Actually, ALB Ingress controller parses configuration for the load balancer from the Ingress YAML definition file and then apply [Target groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html) one per Kubernetes service with specified instances and [NodePorts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) exposed on a particular nodes. On the top level [Listeners](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html) expose connection port for Load Balancer and make decision for request routing according to defined routing rules as per official AWS ALB Ingress Controller Workflow [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/coreos-and-ticketmaster-collaborate-to-bring-aws-application-load-balancer-support-to-kubernetes/).

Just after a short theory tour, I have a few concerns about you current configuration:

1. First, I would recommend to check AWS ALB Ingress Controller
   [setup](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/controller/setup/) and inspect the relevant logs:

`kubectl logs -n kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | egrep -o "alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")`

And then verify whether Load Balancer has been successfully generated within AWS [console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/#LoadBalancers:sort=loadBalancerName).

2. Inspect **Target groups** for particular ALB in order to ensure whether
   [health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html) checks for k8s instances all are good.
3. Ensure, whether **Security groups** contain appropriate firewall rules for your instances in order to allow inbound and outbound network traffic across ALB.

I encourage you to get familiar with dedicated chapter about HTTP to HTTPS redirection in the official AWS ALB Ingress Controller [documentation](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/tasks/ssl_redirect/).

Comment: i want my setup to be aws api gateway -->ambassador/traefik ---> eks alb load balancer

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have for my cluster to run on https.

In my ingress/Load balancer:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: CERT
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
    # ports using the ssl certificate
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    # which protocol a Pod speaks
```

In my Ingress controller, configMap of the nginx configuration:

```
    app.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: my case should it be alb.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true" ?

Comment: I think it would still be app, but you should try both, I have a classic LB and I'm using nginx as an ingress inside.

Comment: I am controlling this in the nginx configuration , nginx.conf file although not ideal  .This is my temp solution , other solutions provided in the thread does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
```

https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/tasks/ssl_redirect/